# C# Infinite value error when casting/not casting

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I think this will be an easy one, i think im missing something.

```
if (((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50) && (row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != null))
```

this code gives me the error that when casting cant be a number that is infinite.

Ive also tried:

```
if (((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50) && ((string)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != null))
if (((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50) && (row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != ""))
```

any help would be great!

Im using winforms in visual studio 10 using C#.

error: "When casting from a number, the value must be less than infinite"

More of the Code if your interested:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            //countpg
            //countPg++;
            pgtothold = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
            countPg += pgtothold;

            //if (((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50) && (row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != null))
            if ((Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Pareto"].Value)) && ((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50)
            {
                //top 50
                //top++;
                tempTop = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
                top += tempTop;
            }
            else
                if (((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value > 50) && ((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 100) && (row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != ""))
                {
                    //50-100
                    tempMidt = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
                    tmid += tempMidt;
                }
                else
```

Comment: What exact error do you get? Also you want to check for null before you cast.

Comment: (row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != null) should be first if you want shortcut evaluation to do its job

Comment: As an aside, you're checking for null AFTER you cast to integer. Re-order your statements to check for null first.

Comment: What is the actual value of `row.Cells["Pareto"].Value` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Swap the conditions around, otherwise the first one will always throw an exception if the value is null.

Comment: re-ordered, same error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use:

```
var data =  System.Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Pareto"].Value);
   if( data <=50 )
   {
    ----
   }
```

that will fail to 0 if the content is DBNull ( if this is acceptable ), so your code will result cleaner and safer.

Comment: wouldnt that mean im converting null into an int? therefore infinite?

Comment: @StevenSmith try the suggested code and see if it works. If don't try to Convert.ToDouble(...).

Comment: currently error occuring, talking about converting int to bool

Comment: if ((Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Pareto"].Value ! = null) && (int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50))  cannot convert double to bool

Comment: @StevenSmith don't check for null, write only the code I proposed, that handles internally the null case!

Comment: ah i see, didnt relise, ill give it a try

Comment: if ((Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Pareto"].Value)) && ((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50))  cannot use && operator on double and bool

Comment: remove the second part, do the thest on the result of the convert, see the updated reply

Comment: hmm not sure how to impliment that in my code without a crazy amount of ifs, ill update my post and show you more of the code

Comment: just relised there are 2 types of null, normal null, and a dbo null never even relised there was 2 types hehe.  all sorted now thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != null) && ((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50))
```

I think you want this. If the thing is null, it doesn't evaluate the rest of the AND.

Comment: Break it up into multiple ifs to figure out exactly what's happening. If the issue is that the value is null, this should work. So there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

The result from the datatable is most likely of type decimal. So try this:

```
if (((decimal)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50.0m) && (row.Cells["Pareto"].Value != null))
```